# O que são widgets?

Tags: android, android-studio, terminologia, widget

Entendo que os *widgets* seriam os componentes disponibilizados na paleta do Android Studio, por exemplo. Assim, os componente da paleta abaixo, não só os que estão no grupo Widgets (mostrados na figura), mas também *constraints*, *buttons*, *texts* e *layouts* são *widgets*.

[image: IDE]

No entanto, fico confuso quando se fala em *widgets*, pois poderia ser também aqueles pequenos aplicativos com previsão do tempo, relógio, atualização de redes sociais, etc.

A definição que apresentei está correta? Por que existe essa confusão? Por que os pequenos aplicativos (ou funcionalidade de um *app*) são chamados de *widgets*? O conceito de *widget*, mais correto, não seria só para os componentes da paleta de programação?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Meio que cada um pode dar sua definição já que muito do que usamos de TI são termos cunhados por alguém e adotados pelo mercado meio que sem critério, estudo ou questionamento. Algumas coisas são adotadas de formas diferentes de acordo com o gosto de quem adotou partindo do seu entendimento.

[Pela Wikipedia vemos algumas definições diferentes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget) e se for conferir aumenta a confusão, cada página fala uma coisa. [Uma das páginas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_(GUI)) fala da possível etimologia que seria *window gadgets* e eu fico com ela. Então um *widget* é um componente de software pronto que está relacionado com algum controle de apresentação e/ou interação com o usuário usado em um sistema gráfico de janelas. Não vejo porque fazer distinção entre desktop, mobile ou web.

Não vejo porque impor limites artificiais sobre eles além do que foi definido acima então se atender esse critério qualquer coisa está valendo. Pra mim um botão e alguns outros componentes são *widgets*. Outros IDEs são assim também, alguns nem chamam essas coisas de *widgets*.

A Google é conhecida por lançar coisas beta como definitivas e depois como foi lançado fica complicado corrigir. A Google é uma dessas empresas que se dizem ágeis que prezam por faz MVP e dentro dessa filosofia o importante é por na rua alguma coisa e ver o que acontece, ir adaptando. Isso nunca funcionou bem, sempre gera produtos capengas ou confusão para os usuários, mas há uma corrente que prega que isto é melhor do que procurar a excelência, boa definição, algo bem pensado. Este parece um caso que não pensaram muito, fizeram. Se bobear acharam que era uma forma melhor de organizar porque fica bem separado no IDE, não importa se a definição está correta.

No fundo acho que não faz muita diferença onde está.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).